# Download images with bash until url invalid

Tags: bash, wget

Similar to [Download images from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442841/download-images-from-website)

I'd like to download a list of images from a website where the url is having -number at the end. I was thinking of a simple loop that counts up like

```
#!/bin/bash
baseurl=https://www.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/gallery/2016/dec/23/prayer-around-the-world-in-pictures-religion#img-
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
do  
  wget $baseurl-$c
done
```

But how can I break out of the loop when there is no valid picture any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Baurin Leza

your answer pointed me in the right direction. The following script works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
baseurl=http://www.novomestskykuryr.info/01-sada-02/fotogalerie-94/slides/img
for (( c=100; c<=200; c++ ))
do  
  wget $baseurl-$c.jpg || break
done
```

Answer (score 3):

you can  use || for do another command if wget $baseurl-$c fail, like this:

```
wget $baseurl-$c || echo "Some log to log file" > ./my_log.log
```

Comment: this doesn't break out of the loop at all, though the general idea is here